# Error on twitter api 1.1

Tags: java, twitter

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Boolean isSuccess = false;

    try {

        //Consumer key
        String consumerKey = STATICVALUES.consumerKey;
        //Consumer secret       
        String consumerSecret = STATICVALUES.consumerSecret;    

        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();           

        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey ,consumerSecret);

        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(params[0], params[1]);

        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);               

        twitter.updateStatus(params[2]);
        Log.e("TAG", "true");

        isSuccess = true;
    }       
    catch (TwitterException e) {

        isSuccess = false;
        Log.e("TAG", "fail");

        e.printStackTrace();


    }       

    return isSuccess;

}
```

this is my code.
i use twitter4j-2.0.2 core. and i have a error, as you know, error about api 1.1
so i add twitter4j 3.0.3 core, but nothing's change.

i search about twitter api 1.1, but someone just add twitter4j 3.0.3 core, someone need change xml to json.

i write to editbox, and click button, this text send tiwtter.
what can i do? i need help!

Comment: Please specify which error you are getting.

Comment: http://blogfiles.naver.net/20131001_186/h_wan92_1380593511396Njqpt_PNG/Untitled-1.png

Comment: this is my logcat. when i use try{}catch{}, I already have the error output.

Comment: First of all, when clicking the link you provided, you get access denied.

Comment: I remember using JTwitter some time ago. If you are interested I'll post my (small) implementation. I did not do it already since you specified twitter4j.

Comment: I know I rude, but do this for me, please?

Comment: First of all, I will NOT do it for you. But I may help you, based on your shown effort. If you want a good question you must reveal at least some background, such as what kind of error you are getting, stack trace, etc.

Comment: And finally, is it a requirement that you use twitter4j or can you use other API, such as JTwitter? If so, I can provide you a fairly small implementation to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

https://github.com/vshivam/privly-android/blob/master/src/ly/priv/mobile/TwitterLinkGrabberService.java#L120

Dependencies :

/privly-android/libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar

/privly-android/libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar

/privly-android/libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar

Comment: TwitterLinkGrabberService.java and TwitterHelperMethods.java just two source. Only these even okay?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.